# How to exclude certain CSS class/element in Ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

What is the method in which I can still display the icons that I want, (in this case, characters of the Coptic alphabet) while still retaining and not overriding the menu back icon? As you will be able to see in the image, the back icon is not being displayed. I'd like to exclude this icon from the rest of the icons so the characters can still be displayed correctly while the back icon is also displayed correctly.

I've tried

```
:not(ion-icon name="menu") {
}
```

but that didn't work.

**HTML code**

```
<!--
  Generated template for the CopticLanguagePage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>Coptic Language</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>


<ion-content class="background">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon class="fa-alpha-upper" item-start></ion-icon>
            Alpha
          <ion-icon class="fa-alpha-lower" item-end></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-icon class="fa-beta-upper" item-start></ion-icon>
              Beta
            <ion-icon class="fa-beta-lower" item-end></ion-icon>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>


</ion-content>
```

**SCSS Code**

```
page-coptic-language {
    body, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ion-icon,  {
        font-family: 'Coptic' !important
    }
}
```

[image: Image showing an incorrect back icon with correct Coptic characters]

Thanks for your time and patience

- A novice dev

Answer (score 0):

since `back` is a button and `ionic` adds a class `back-button` to that, you can add css to `back-button` bu using the parent selector.

**Html:**

```
<ion-header class="coptic-font">
    <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>Coptic Language</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
```

**Css:**

```
.coptic-font {
    .back-button      {
        font-family: 'inherit' !important // your css
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the parent selector in this case?

Comment: it is your component name, which you have taken in your project. If you want the same for all pages, then only the `.back-button` may work.

Comment: The back button does appear correctly on pages that are not using the coptic font. I'm still confused on how to implement the above code. Forgive me

Comment: check m updated answer, you can give a parent class to header and button may be inside that header, check that once,

Comment: is that style applying? move that to bottom of your styles and apply any css and test if it is working, like changing the color and all. I just tested and it worked for my case.

Comment: Does not appear so. I've inserted the code in both app.scss and the pages scss

Comment: inspect and check back-button class is beibg appled in your case?

Comment: From the dev. console it appears it is being applied however the back icon is still not showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168617/discussion-between-sravan-and-abbanoob).